# Is this SP safe to SQL Injection?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_Test] (
     @param nvarchar(Max)
) AS BEGIN

DECLARE @Output nvarchar(Max) = 
N’Select ‘ + @param

Select @output
Return
```

### Intended Use

`exec sp_test ‘5’`

Returns “select 5”

### Malicious Use

`exec sp_test ‘5; drop database’`

Returns(would be safe):
“select 5; drop database“

—-OR—-

Returns(not safe):
“select 5”
...but also actually dropping the database

MS SQL Server

Comment: select 5 will not be so usefull... is there a part of your query missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried to run the proc for the malicious use case? If not, try it on a test system (and be sure you have a backup because you'll need it if the proc is run by a privileged account).

Answer (score 1):

All your stored procedure is doing is to put “select” in front of whatever is passed in. It doesn’t run anything.

But presumably you’re going to then ask something else to run whatever comes back, and that could be unsafe. If you’re wanting a very dynamic querying environment, then read what Erland Sommarskog has to say on the matter at http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rob! My account is too new to up-vote it. I figured that a select SP couldn't change it's query plan, but wanted to double-check. You are correct in extrapolating that a 2nd account is used to execute the dynamic SQL returned by this SP. That second account only has `GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT:: [ReportDataTable] TO [Account2]`

Comment: You should be able accept the answer it though...